# More helpful to keep duplicate questions or delete them?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

If I have a question correctly marked as a duplicate question, is it more useful for me to delete it to reduce clutter or leave it for future searchers who might have interpreted the question similarly to myself?

Comment: It depends on how dissimilar the dupe is to the dupe target, how many other dupes exist for the question, etc, etc. Basically: how useful would the duplicate be as a sign-post.

Comment: it turns out this question was a duplicate...

Answer (score -3):

> **Should duplicates be deleted?**
>
> In general, no: most duplicates stay around. Having multiple copies of the same question with different wording is useful as search fodder, because people looking for an answer may use different wording too.
>
> Duplicates that are word-for-word copies or that are so poorly written that they are not useful may be deleted by users with sufficient privilege.

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)